# How to handle multiple asynchronous operations that can both delete the same file?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, logging, fs

If I have asynchronous function that is called by API, that function checks the log file `current.log` size, if it exceeded a limit, it should copy it to the `old.log` file and delete the contents of `current.log` file afterwards.

```
function checkSizeCopyAndDelete(){
     if(size>1024){
          //delete old file contents 
          fs.truncate(oldLogFile,()=>{
               //copy current file contents to the old file
               fs.copyFile(currentLogFile, oldLogFile, ()=>{
                    //then delete the currentLogFile that was copied to the oldLogFile
                    fs.truncate(currentLogFile ,()=>{
                         //done, now we should add the new data to be logged to currentLogFile
                    })
               })
          })

     }
}
```

If I used `fs.copyFile` and not `fs.copyFileSync`,
How to handle a scenario that the event loop got 2 different truncate function calls based on `checkSizeCopyAndDelete` finding the size at both calls 1024+, 
 then 1 of the truncate calls was executed and deleted the file, then even before the second truncate it did copy the file.

Now the 2nd truncate will still be executed (and delete the new `old.log` file that was just filled) because it has no idea that the `current.log` file size became 0, and then copy, leaving us the `old.log` file with the content of the new `current.log` file, instead of having the 1024+ KBs data that was supposed to be there but was deleted.

Do I have to use the synchronous versions in this scenario ?

Comment: In which scenario the API will call multiple times to do that specific job at the same time?
If you are using a HTTP API, why are you doing that? A cron job wouldn't fit better?
In any situation, would be better if you block new operations when one start.

Answer (score 0):

You can force asynchronous operations to occur sequentially by setting up a promise mutex and continually appending to the promise chain.

```
let chkSzTex = Promise.resolve();
async function checkSizeCopyAndDelete(){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    chkSzTex = chkSzTex.then(()=>new Promise((res2,rej2)=>{
      if(size<=1024)
        return res2();
      //delete old file contents 
      fs.truncate(oldLogFile,(err)=>{
        if(err)
          return rej2(err);
        //copy current file contents to the old file
        fs.copyFile(currentLogFile, oldLogFile, (err)=>{
          if(err)
            return rej2(err);
          //then delete the currentLogFile that was copied to the oldLogFile
          fs.truncate(currentLogFile ,(err)=>{
            if(err)
              return rej2(err);
            //done, now we should add the new data to be logged to currentLogFile
            res2();
          })
        })
      })
    }).then(resolve).catch(reject)
  })
}
```